# Error intstalling AppKit: Could not build wheels for pygobject which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python, appkit, pyautogui, pyobjc

I have been trying to install AppKit but keep on getting this error:
[image: Failed building wheel for pygobject Running setup.py clean for pygobject Failed to build pygobject Could not build wheels for pygobject which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly]

How do I go about it ?

Comment: Could you provide more information: (a) what is the name of the package you are installing, (b) on what platform?   The error is not related to the PyObjC bindings for AppKit on macOS, that package has no dependency on pygobject (bindings for GTK+)